# Tabcontrol in Silverlight Navigation Application

Tags: silverlight-4.0, tabcontrol, frame

How to use a common TabControl in Silverlight 4 Navigation Application?
For example, It would be kept at same position in all views like here the Manu bar is kept which has Questions,Tags,Users etc. as headers.

When the user clicks on any TabItem I want to load the respective page in the frame provided by default. I also want the back/forward button of the browser to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you're asking to do this with the TabControl, but I don't think that's what you really want. You could create a "menu bar" consisting of [HyperlinkButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.hyperlinkbutton%28VS.95%29.aspx)s. Use a [Frame](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.frame%28VS.95%29.aspx) as you would a [ContentPlaceHolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.contentplaceholder.aspx) in ASP.NET, where everything outside of the Frame is like a [MasterPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx).

Check out the [Navigation Overview on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838245%28VS.95%29.aspx).

HTH,

Charles